# Change background color of floating action button using my image palette

Tags: android, floating-action-button

Here is my code that I have used to retrieve color from palette. I am able to get the color but unable to set as background color of floating action button.

```
Palette.Swatch vibrantSwatch = palette.getDarkVibrantSwatch();
Palette.Swatch vibrantSwatch2 = palette.getLightVibrantSwatch();

if ( vibrantSwatch != null && vibrantSwatch2 != null) {
    //fb represents my floating action button
    fb.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(vibrantSwatch2.getRgb()));
}
```

Comment: add relevant tag and improve formatting

Comment: remove unwanted spaces

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

**getRGB(int x, int y)**

instead of getRGB().

It returns an integer pixel in the default RGB color model (TYPE_INT_ARGB) and default sRGB colorspace.

Answer (score 0):

No Backgroundcolor named property for floatingAction Button. you can change it using

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/YOURCOLOR"
```

For this you have to import:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```